# vba - error when working with worksheet situated in a closed workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to work on a worksheet situated in another excel file without opening it. To do that, I use an `Excel.Application` object instead of a `workbook` object

I need to sort that worksheet by 2 columns with the sub program `trieTableau2Colonne(ByRef w As Worksheet, ByRef colonne1, ByRef colonne2)`

When I give any worksheet (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets, or worksheet in a open workbook declared with a workbook object), it is working perfectly. But when I use an `Excel.Application` object to work on a closed workbook, it does not work.

The error is about the `SortFields` object of the `Add` method. 
Below, you can see the sub procedure that I wrote, the main program and also a screenshot to show you the error.

An error occurs at the second line of the `trieTableau2Colonne` procedure (`w.Sort.SortFields.Add`). I put a spy in the `w` variable to see what there is inside.

In the second screenshot, we can see the difference between 2 worksheets I use.

- `ws_cible` is a worksheet object obtained from a `workbook` object

  ```
  Dim ws_cible As Worksheet

  Set ws_cible = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Liste Réclas")
  ```

  -->we can read that its type is Worksheet/Feuil1
- w is a `worksheet` object but obtain from an `Excel.Application` object instead of a `workbook` object

  ```
  Dim wb_src As Excel.Application
  Set wb_src = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

  Set ws_src = wb_src.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  ```

  -->we can read that its type is Worksheet/Worksheet

I am convinced that the problem come from that difference but I do not see any difference in the properties or the methods of each object.

```
Sub trieTableau2Colonne(ByRef w As Worksheet, ByRef colonne1, ByRef colonne2)

  w.Sort.SortFields.Clear
  w.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range((colonne1 & ":" & colonne1)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
  w.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    (colonne2 & ":" & colonne2)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
  With w.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A:AZ")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
  End With
End Sub

' main program'


    Dim ws_src As Worksheet
    Dim wb_src As Excel.Application
    Set wb_src = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ChDir Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Path
    stfile = Application.GetOpenFilename

    If stfile = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With wb_src
        .Workbooks.Open (stfile)
        .Visible = False
    End With
    Set ws_src = wb_src.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'MsgBox (ws_src.Cells(1, 1).Value)
    Call trieTableau2Colonne(ws_src, "E", "B")
```

#### IDE window screenshot

[image: error occured and spy]

#### variable watch window screenshot

[image: spy]

Comment: You have to call `wb_src.Workbooks.Open()` or `wb_src.Workbooks.Add()`before you reference a `Worksheet`.

Comment: Can you edit your question and translate the error message and show us which line the error is on

Comment: You need to qualify **all** your `Range` objects with the `w` workbook.

Comment: I do not really understand what do you mean by qualifying all my `Range` object by the `w` workbook.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, you reference Worksheet before you open a workbook. You can't get a `Worksheet` from `Excel.Application`. You get a `Worksheet` from a `Workbook` object.

```
Dim wb_src As Excel.Application
Set wb_src = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set ws_src = wb_src.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Try adding `wb_src.Workbooks.Open()` or `wb_src.Workbooks.Add()` before you reference a Worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

Indeed, in my main program I have well opened the workbook

```
With wb_src
  .Workbooks.Open (stfile)
  .Visible = False
End With
```

I can see that I access correctly to that file by putting a msgbox to check a the content of a cell inside and it works well :

```
MsgBox (ws_src.Cells(1, 1).Value)
```

Comment: You should modify your question with updated code instead of posting an answer that isn't really an answer to your question. Can you translate the error and show me the line it errors on? I will update my answer if I am able to figure out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: The error occurs at the second line of the sub procedure trieTableau2Colonne : 'w.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range((colonne1 & ":" & colonne1)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _xlSortNormal' . The message error is "La méthode 'Add' de l'objet 'SortFileds' a échoué"

Comment: I put 2 screenshots above to show the message error and the content of my variables using spys